# trigger drag and drop event by attributes

Tags: php, jquery, html

How can I track drag and drop event if I have more elements, like I have 4 div

```
<div data-val="val-1">Menu 1</div>
<div data-val="val-2">Menu 2</div>
<div data-val="val-3">Menu 3</div>
<div data-val="val-4">Menu 4</div>
```

and I have 8 list items

```
<ul>
    <li id="something-1">Something 1</li>
    <li id="something-2">Something 2</li>
    <li id="something-3">Something 3</li>
    <li id="something-4">Something 4</li>
    <li id="something-5">Something 5</li>
    <li id="something-6">Something 6</li>
    <li id="something-7">Something 7</li>
    <li id="something-8">Something 8</li>
</ul>
```

If I drag `li` having Id `something-3` into div having `data-val="val-2"`, How can post it to a file that should post both values.

Comment: What do you mean by post it to a file ?, you mean save the menu configuration ?, where do you want to save it, in a json file ?, in a database ?*

Comment: I want to save it into database

Comment: Post mean using jquery ajax or post function or anything else

Answer (score 1):

Using the jquery UI function [sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) and some [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) :

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $( "ul" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected",
    receive: function(event, elem) {
        var menu = $(this).data('val');
        var item = $(elem.item[0]).attr('id');
        $.post('yourphp.php', { item: item, menu: menu }, function () {
        console.log('Menu configuration saved !');
        });
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>Menu 1</h1>
<ul class="connected" data-val="menu-1">
    <li id="something-1">Something 1</li>
    <li id="something-2">Something 2</li>
    <li id="something-3">Something 3</li>
    <li id="something-4">Something 4</li>
    <li id="something-5">Something 5</li>
</ul>
<h1>Menu 2</h1>
<ul class="connected" data-val="menu-2">
    <li id="something-6">Something 6</li>
    <li id="something-7">Something 7</li>
</ul>
<h1>Menu 3</h1>
<ul class="connected" data-val="menu-3">
    <li id="something-8">Something 8</li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/11522/)